# make Tab the autocomplete shortcut in the Python Console

Tags: python, shortcut

When working in the *Python Console* inside of Blender, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> is the default keyboard shortcut for autocomplete. And there is also an *Autocomplete* button on the console bar that can be clicked.

However, when working with Python files outside of Blender, I am used to <kbd>Tab</kbd> being the autocomplete shortcut. So when I want to autocomplete in Blender, I often press <kbd>Tab</kbd> by mistake, which has the effect of indenting the line that my cursor is on.

**Is there a way to make <kbd>Tab</kbd> serve as the autocomplete shortcut instead of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>?**

Answer (score 5):

I figured this out myself. Go to **Edit → Preferences**, then to **Keymap → Console**. From there you can change the **Console Autocomplete** to whatever shortcut you'd like (and change or disable the **Indent** shortcut).

Answer (score 5):

An intelligent Tab key appears to be the default in 2.8x.

When used it creates Tabs in the white-space at the start of a line, otherwise it Autocompletes when used after text characters.